# Error MT5209 -Native linking error xamarin in Visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

> Error MT5209: Native linking error: file not found: -lsqlite3 (MT5209)

I am getting this error in visual studio(Xamarin ios).while compile the code

**I have tried the following solution some one posted in stack overflow** but even it is not working.

> Download nuget packages of Xamarin.Build.Download
>
> To work around the issue you will need to edit the targets file
>   packages/Xamarin.Build.Download.0.2.0/build/Xamarin.Build.Download.targets
>
> Add a AfterTargets="AssignProjectConfiguration" attribute to the
>   _XamarinBuildDownload target.

```
<Target
        Name="_XamarinBuildDownload"
        DependsOnTargets="_XamarinBuildDownloadCore;_XamarinBuildAddDownloadedItems"
        AfterTargets="AssignProjectConfiguration"
        Condition="'@(XamarinBuildDownload)'!=''"
        />
```

Comment: Did you download the stated sqlite version (3) with NuGet?

Comment: send the content of your nuget.config file here

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the native linker cannot find a symbol that is referenced somewhere. There are several reasons this may happen, you can find out more details here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/troubleshooting/mtouch-errors/#MT5210

Answer (score 0):

Goto iOS project properties and select Don't Link user linker option & rebuild solution.